# Why is ffmpeg's hstack so much slower than overlay and pad?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using ffmpeg to stitch together two videos of people chatting into a video with each of them side-by-side, like this:

[image: left.mp4 + right.mp4 = out.mp4]

Here's the command I'm currently using to get this done, which runs at ~2.5x on my 13" M1 MacBook Pro:

```sh
ffmpeg -y -i left.mp4 -i right.mp4 -filter_complex "
  [0:v] crop=w=in_w/2 [croppedLeft];
  [1:v][1:v] overlay=x=overlay_w/4 [shiftedRight];
  [shiftedRight][croppedLeft] overlay [vout];
  [0:a][1:a] amix [aout]
" -map "[vout]" -map "[aout]" -ac 2 out.mp4
```

This command crops the left video to half of its original width (cropping so the video is centered), then shifts the right video a quarter of its width to the right, then overlays the left video on the left half of the output merged with the shifted right video.

One day on my weekly fun-time read-through the [FFmpeg filters documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html) I stumbled on a filter named [`hstack`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#hstack), which is described as being "faster than using overlay and pad filter to create same output."

My ex wife can affirm that there are few higher priorities in my life than going faster, so I altered my ffmpeg script to use `hstack` instead of two `overlay`s:

```sh
ffmpeg -y -i left.mp4 -i right.mp4 -filter_complex "
  [0:v] crop=w=in_w/2 [croppedLeft];
  [1:v] crop=w=in_w/2 [croppedRight];
  [croppedLeft][croppedRight] vstack [vout];
  [0:a][1:a] amix [aout]
" -map "[vout]" -map "[aout]" -ac 2 out.mp4
```

...but that command runs *painfully* slowly, like 0.1x. It takes multiple minutes to render a single second.

So uhhh what's going on here? Why is hstack taking so long when it's supposed to be faster?

I've tried this on both the M1 native build from [OSXExperts](http://www.osxexperts.net/) (version N-99816-g3da35b7) and [the standard ffmpeg from brew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/ffmpeg#default) and hstack is just as slow on each.

Comment: Likely because the first input doesn't have a valid fps set. Switch the order in hstack and check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @Gyan commented, the problem was that neither of my files had a valid fps set.

They came from [Riverside.fm](https://riverside.fm), which recently added a "consistent framerate" video file output. Using those files made `hstack` export between 3.5 and 4x.

I'm not sure how to give files valid framerates in ffmpeg, but now I know that's why `hstack` was so slow.

Comment: Thanks @cgenco for updating! I'm also using Riverside and want to accomplish something similar :)

Comment: See https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/ChangingFrameRate

Comment: I just had the same problem with vstack and mine had the same issue as well, thank you very much.